# Why does my Makefile build an non-existent source file?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, compilation

I have the following makefile which is supposed to build procdriver.c and thus output a .ko file. The issue is that even when I delete procdriver.c my makefile seems to be able to build a procdriver.ko file. I would like to try to find out from where it gets the source file it is building every time.

```
TARGET = procdriver

obj-m := procdriver.o 
procdriver-objs+= gpioLib.o

KDIR:= /home/pi/myRpi/linux
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all: gpioLib.o procdriver.c
    echo<<"in all"
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules 
    rm -r -f .tmp_versions *.mod.c .*.cmd *.o *.symvers 



gpioLib.o: gpioLib.c gpioLib.h 
    gcc -c gpioLib.c -o gpioLib.o

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

This is the output from the Makefile: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23575533/

**EDIT**

the entire output of the remake command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23577274

I think this is the most important bit of output: http://pastebin.com/0vj9aNMg

Comment: Typically makefiles don't build source files.

Comment: @Olaf what would you suggest in that case? Because evern when I delete procdriver.c it outputs a procdriver.ko file. Which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Use `remake` to debug `Makefile`-s

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you I tried the remake command I think this is the most important bit of output: http://pastebin.com/0vj9aNMg As you can see suddenly it still manages to make procdriver.o

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the entire output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23577274/

Comment: @Olaf ^ I posted some additional output in case that might give a clue.

Comment: This is not part of the question text, btw. After 1.5 years, you should know [ask]!

Comment: @Olaf I'll add this output to the main text.

Comment: @Olaf strange thing is that even when I am in the root directory and do: sudo find . -name "procdriver" it doesn't find anything. So I don't get how this makefile can even work!

Comment: @Olaf Typically Makefiles will at least try to build source files (from yacc/lex files, or by checking out RCS or SCCS files.) But I don't think that's the problem here...

Comment: when defining macros, unless that macro has dynamic contents, use `:=` rather than `=`

Comment: in general, do not use a `-` in macro names

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you, I applied the few things you mentionned but unfortunately didn't solve my issue :/

Comment: this line: echo<<"in all" is the beginning of an inline file (which is never terminated. Perhaps you meant: `# in all`  Which will be echoed to the terminal because it is part of a 'recipe'

Comment: @user3629249 you mean like this: http://pastebin.com/sjubSCzv
If yes: that didn't solve the issue. The goal of this line is just to echo something to the terminal to debug my makefile.

Comment: @user3629249 moving that echo below the rm line doesn't solve it neither. So I am not really sure the echo is causing the issue.

Comment: @Jens: That's why I did not write "makenfiles don't ...", but use a less absolute phrase. Btw: as we are nit-picking: it is not the makefile which creates any files. Makefiles only contain rules (and related).

Comment: @trilolil: 1) Don't `sudo` unless you have to! 2) It is understandable `find` does not find `procdriver.c` with that argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
obj-m := procdriver.o 
procdriver-objs+= gpioLib.o
```

is wrong. It says that the sole object file for the module will be `procdriver.o`
and that the build system is to generate that one from `procdriver-objs`

`procdriver-objs` is initally empty and so becomes = `gpioLib.o`. So `gpioLib.o`
is the only object prerequisite of `procdriver.o`; hence `gpioLib.c` and `gpioLib.h`
are the only source prerequisites of `procdriver.o`. `procdriver.c` is redundant.

You want (I believe) to make a module from a pair of object files `procdriver.o` and `gpioLib.o`,
compiled respectively from the corresponding `.c` files. The way you need to express that is:

```
obj-m += my-module-name.o
my-module-name-objs := procdriver.o gpioLib.o
```

You will have to rethink your filenames to avoid a collision between `my-module-name.o`
and `procdriver.o`. Consult the documentation [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide: 2.7. Modules Spanning Multiple Files](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x351.html).

Much of the content of your makefile is redundant. As far as I can see all it
needs is:

```
obj-m += my-module-name.o
my-module-name-objs := procdriver.o gpioLib.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean

gpioLib.o: gpioLib.h
```